# Modular Application using MVVM, Prism, WPF and MEF - Examples / Tutorials

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I am working on a modular application and have decided to restart and integrate Prism into what I'm trying to create instead of trying to re-create the wheel.

Requirements:

- Easily Updated with new Functionality (UI / Services)
- WPF (Not Silverlight, esp now that MS has said no more updates :()
- Shared Library that houses common tasks / services
- Ability to block access to DLL imports / methods based on AD groups
- Compatible with something like AvalonDock

For example:

Regular User: Access to view, create, modify, special tool 1

Power User: Access to view, create, modify, delete, special tool 1, special tool 2

Should I go with a MVVM Framework such as MVVM Light or does Prism (v4) good enough support for MVVM for WPF (All examples I've seen use Silverlight) for a large scale application?

Are there some good resources out there? I've tried searching but mostly find people asking the same question from months / years ago. I've read most of the Developers Guide to Microsoft Prism but it doesn't have many examples and is more of an overview of how Prism works, and the examples it does have for MVVM are Silverlight based.

Are there books you'd recommend? I've looked at Building Enterprise Applications with WPF and MVVM but it doesn't have the best reviews and most people say its also pretty short when it comes to the code / details.

Comment: Well looks like the question was closed, what would make it less localized? I can't be the only one using WPF, MVVM, Prism and MEF...

Comment: Too bad I can't give Will -1 for closing the question.  I'm trying to find good patterns and resources for doing this very thing.

Comment: @bporter you might want to check out http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/ he has created his "Ocean" library that helps out with MVVM and Prism. There is a betaish version available from his Boise talk / demo and he is planning on releasing the next "full" version in the next few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you watched the Prism videos that are on Pluralsight?  It is a subscription site, but you could always signup for the 10 day free trial.

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=prism-introduction

Comment: No, I've watched their MVC3 videos which were quite nice and free but haven't looked. I'll take a look to see what they offer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice your name until just now, excellent job on covering Prism. The only thing I would have liked was more MEFed versions since you covered mostly Unity, but it still helped a lot and the MEF examples were quite nice. Thanks again it was a good starting point. Still trying to work in Avalondock with MVVM in the modules.

Comment: Thanks for the Video Series, I have watched it. Now I am trying to implement same using MEF. But have problems. Can you please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316189/how-to-register-views-for-navigation