# How to register Views for Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I have the project structure as follows:

```
Modules
   --- ModuleA
         ---ViewA
         ---ViewModelA
         ---Module
   --- ModuleB
         ---ViewB
         ---ViewModelB
         ---Module
MyApplication
   ---Shell.xaml
   ---Bootstrapper
MyApplication.Infrastructure
   ---
   ---
```

Now, In ModuleA.Module:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(Module), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class Module : IModule
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Module(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ViewA));
    }
}
```

Now, In ModuleB.Module:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(Module), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class Module : IModule
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Module(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ViewB));
    }
}
```

In Shell.xaml:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Show View A" />
        <MenuItem Header="Show View B" />
    </Menu>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"/>

</DockPanel>
```

In Bootstrapper.cs

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(BootStrapper).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(RegionNames).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ModuleA.Module).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ModuleB.Module).Assembly));
}
```

When I run the application, I get an error specifying that No Exports or Multiple Exports were found for ContentRegion. I can understand that I am registering both of my views in the same region, so I get that error.

But I don't know how to register my views for navigation purpose, so that when I click on MenuItem `Show View A`, ViewA should appear in Content Region. Similarly for ViewB.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476745/how-to-register-modules-in-prism-6-wpf-application-with-view-switching-navigatio

Comment: @R.Richards That's using Unity. I want to use Mef.

Comment: Sorry about that. How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301926/wpf-prism-request-navigate-activation-error/33303082#33303082

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks for the links but they did not provide enough information.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reading the docs?

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/60-Navigation.md#prism-region-overview

Using MEF, you can simply export the view type with the specified name.

```
[Export("InboxView")]
public partial class InboxView : UserControl
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But How do I attach this view with specific menuItem? Is it same as Unity or any Difference??

Comment: Also, they use this.container everywhere in the examples. What is the type of that container???

Comment: Also, when I register both modules in Bootstrapper, I get an error. But If I register any one of them, then no Errors. So, How Should I register them??? Thanks for help.

Comment: Honestly, I don't use MEF.  It's not an IoC container.  You will have to read the docs and go through the samples https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf